# Set indexer to manual

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, indexing

How do you set indexer to manual in magento2?

I do not see any option under `bin/magento`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as manual indexing on Magento 2 anymore.

The two modes available are:

- **realtime** which is the equivalent of M1 **update on save**
- **schedule** which sets the specified indexers to save according to the cron schedule.

To change the indexing mode via the CLI you can run:

```
magento indexer:set-mode {schedule|realtime} [indexer]
```

For example:

```
magento indexer:set-mode schedule catalog_category_product catalog_product_category
```

Comment: With schedule however how do you set the schedule?  I asked this question here as i want to schedule them for say midnight but i cant find any more information about scheduling https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209069/magento-2-indexers-run-by-schedule-running-every-minute